# Fedora 17 auto login does not work

Tags: fedora, kde, auto-login

The Fedora 17 auto login feature does not work through the GUI in KDE:

```
System Settings -> Login Screen -> Convenience -> Enable Auto Login.
```

It accepts the changes, but when I reboot, I am still prompted to select a username and type a password.  The GUI seems to be broken.   Screenshot:

[image]

So if this GUI bit doesn't work, how can I enable autologin on fedora 17?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Adding "Automatic Login" feature in Fedora 17.**
>
> The automatic login feature will automatically login as a specific user each time you boot the computer. Use this feature only on a single user machine as it will not provide you with an option to login as another user.
>
> Note: Fedora 13 does not automatically select Auto-Login.  However, if manually selected at GDM automatic login will commence.
>
> Note: GDM will not allow you to auto-login as root!  You must choose a normal user for this feature.
>
> Note: If you intend to use the Timed Login feature you cannot use Automatic Login. You must choose one or the other.

Here are the steps:

1. Edit the following file: **/etc/gdm/custom.conf**
2. Make a backup copy of the custom.conf as custom.conf.bak  So you can rollback should something go wrong.
3. You should see rows that look like this:

   ```
   [daemon]
   [security]
   [xdmcp]
   [greeter]
   [chooser]
   [debug]
   ```
4. Enter the following lines under the [daemon] line, replace 'el' with your username you want to login with:

   ```
   [daemon]
   AutomaticLoginEnable=true
   AutomaticLogin=el
   ```
5. Save and exit.  Reboot your computer and should auto log in as your specified user.

Source: [Custom GDM Configuration For Auto And Timed Login](http://fedorasolved.org/Members/Dp67/custom-gdm-configuration-for-auto-and-timed-login)

Answer (score 4):

For KDE, in `/etc/kde/kdm/kdmrc` set `AutoLoginEnable` and `AutoLoginUser`.

This works in a Fedora 16.

Answer (score 1):

This particular setting requires root access to change. Try logging in as root and changing the setting.

Comment: The window prompts user for the root password when I choose the "apply" button.  So it knows I need root access to make a change.  I was never able to get it to work, but I found the work around described below by editing custom.conf.

Answer (score 0):

You could just go to System Settings -> User Accounts -> Select your user and click Auto Login

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?  If you use KDE, that doesn't work.